# SVN - display files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

What I want to achieve is just to download files from repository through ssh+svn// protocol (tortoiseSVN) into my computer, and not to mess up anything with the svn itself.

Is export function safe to use? Won't is mess anything up on the svn repo, delete or disable anything? Just copy files into my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, export is safe to use. Export will give you a copy of the source files and changes to those files will not be tracked. Here is the documentation on the export command:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Comment: Thnaks, and just to make 100% sure - fully recursive, head revision (omit externals checked out) is ok?

Comment: Yes, you won't be modifying the repository you're exporting the code from.